# Is this a list question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A somewhat continuation of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) and [this argument](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8202364#8202364) we had on The Bridge.

I've been trying to ask [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106328/what-gun-scopes-correlate-to-their-manufacturer) on Gaming.SE. Apparently though, everyone else on Arqade seems to disagree with me.  I've read the first linked question, most notably this quote:

> List questions are generally off-topic everywhere in the SE network. –
>   Robert Harvey♦

My question is, is the following question a list question then? It hasn't been closed, the site it's on is part of the SE network, and I have a hard time distinguishing this and the meta post about lists.

Is this a list question? If so, is it a bad question then?

[BICYCLING](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index)

Comment: Some list questions are there for reference purpose, when there are no existing list elsewhere and *the community* finds it helpful to have all the information gathered in one place, rather than having to search the Internet all over again.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the question, but someone will probably say that it better belongs on the BL2 wiki or some shit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, each site has slightly different policies on list questions (so it is better to ask meta.gaming).

Since this one is a limited list of 6, it's not really a list question in my eyes (close to being one, though, as well as being "general reference"y). Still this really depends upon the community -- if they feel that it is a list question, it probably is.

The bicycling question you refer to cannot be used as evidence. It was asked before the policy on list questions came into existence, and was "grandfathered" in.

Comment: Amusingly, "grandfathering" seems to be a foreign concept to Arqade, given [this debacle](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/why-was-my-question-about-games-in-a-compilation-closed).

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh: You young whippersnappers don't respect your elders! Why, when I was young, we used to carry our grandfathers wherever they wanted. And it was UPHILL BOTH WAYS! :P

Comment: It's all those video games and rock and roll and drugs, I tell you. :P

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Grandfathering isn't something that we've determined that we need.  Just like SO is clearing up their old, previously allowed questions, so are we.  What need is there for keeping things that are obviously no longer allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to close this as "too localized" (as in, who cares?) than anything else.

According to http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/ weapon sights only ever affect two things:

- Weapon price
- Zoom level

Both of these values are public, as in clearly visible on the weapon card. As a result:

- If you're just playing the game, you don't care because those are not carrying special hidden effects — and you can't affect the parts you get in your random drops anyway
- If you're cheating, you don't care what each scope *looks*, you just want to see which one has the "best" zoom. Hyperion sights seem to zoom the most.

Sooo... who cares what these parts look like?

Comment: I would posit that you *do* care what the scope looks like (or, more accurately, what it looks like when you're staring down it) and want to avoid a scope that is visually cluttered or obscures shooting ability - hence why it was asked at all.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Once you scope in, [they actually are all the same](http://i.imgur.com/0drjEfI.jpg) ([image credit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/18l3vc/weapon_parts_infographic_3_sniper_rifles/))

Comment: That covers sniper rifles. That leaves five weapon families. I've definitely seen different scope appearances when ADS within the same weapon family, so the assertion that they are all "the same" is inaccurate.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh See also rocket launchers ([link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/18issm/weapon_parts_infographic_2_rocket_launchers/)) and SMGs ([link](http://www.reddit.com/tb/18g26i)) and Shotguns ([link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/18ozhc/weapon_parts_infographic_4_shotguns/)) which are a little bit more varied but still fundamentally the same.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Some scopes have a full zoom in (as in within a scope), and some have tinting which makes it harder to see through.  Some are clear. And people who mod save files care.  Don't assume nobody cares. Otherwise we can assume the same thing for all your questions as well.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/are-the-days-and-nights-in-minecraft-of-equal-length/10213#10213 Sooooo......who cares how long a day and a night is?

Comment: @Retrosaur Unrelated; the answer explains why it's important.

Comment: I don't think Zoom levels are shown on the card, are they?

Comment: @Ben ...they are shown on the http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/ which seemed to be painstakingly like the real thing; I don't know about the actual weapon cards.

Answer (score -4):

From reading gaming.SE question, I would see it as being too localized as [badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp) pointed out. According to the FAQ:

**too localized**

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Since your question is focused only to the people who are looking for aesthetic modding, I just don't see it being relevant to general population and therefore being unlikely to help any future visitors.

Also, the question you posted isn't an attempt to solve a problem for you. It is an attempt to let you be lazy and let the community do it for you. You already stated that you can do it yourself, it's just a hassle. Again per the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Since there is no real problem, then the question is technically unanswerable.

Comment: If you think this is an issue of aesthitical modding, you're completely wrong. BL2 is not a vanity game, where all scopes are the same.  Also, "Also, the question you posted isn't an attempt to solve a problem for you. It is an attempt to let you be lazy and let the community do it for you. You already stated that you can do it yourself, it's just a hassle."

Comment: That argument is applicable to every other damned question in gaming then.  Because this is a Q&A site is it not? People ask questions, they get answers.  You've asked some questions as well. Why haven't you answered them yourself?  Maybe you're just as lazy as I am. Hell, even everyone else here.

Comment: Read your question again: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51829/do-scope-readings-scale-to-the-map-size-in-battlefield-3

Comment: You could have done the homework yourself. You could have just researched it on your own.  Yet still you took it upon yourself to let others do the work.

Comment: @Retrosaur Easy, dude.  You need to stop attacking those who disagree with you.  You're not helping yourself at all.

Comment: He attacked me by saying "It is an attempt to let you be lazy and let the community do it for you."

Comment: Sorry, I can't handle hypocrisy. Telling me I'm lazy and not answering the question, yet his own questions are the same.

Comment: @Retrosaur Hypocrisy or not, the correct action is never to attack someone.  As it is, you've damaged your case pretty good.  If you seem unreasonable, why should people risk engaging you?

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think he's damaged his case at all. That could just be my refusal to link with the Meta Hive Mind, though.

Comment: @Rilgon Dude, what's with your attitude lately?  Your hostility is entirely misplaced.  Come join us in chat if you have a problem you want to address.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh [I'd really like to talk about this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7624/conversation-for-rilgon-and-fbueckert)

Comment: My opinions may differ with that of Meta's, does it make my opinion any more invalid than yours?

Comment: I guess i should log on more often so i can reply in a reasonable amount of time. Your question is asking for how the scope looks, not what the stats are, so how is it not a question of aesthetics? If it was a question of what each scope provided in respect to the weapon, then i could see a valid point, however, as your question is, it is only asking for what they look like. If i am wrong in what you're asking, then i restate it and i'll withdraw my argument.

Comment: this IS a Q&A site, however, your not really asking a question. You are making a request. You are asking the community to do something for you and therefore doesn't fit the Q&A format of this site. For your example of my question, i did do the homework. I tested distances in different maps but nothing I came up with was conclusive. I ASKED if someone knew for a fact if the ratios were different. I didn't ask them to test it and give me the results.

Comment: Lastly, i didn't intend to insult you/attack you. I used lazy more as a way of saying that the process was cumbersome and you were looking for an easier way than to specifically call you lazy. I apologize for failing to make my remark properly and making it seem like a personal attack.